# Is the set of adjoint operators weak* closed?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Suppose we have a Banach space $X$ and a net of bounded operators $(T_\gamma)$ on $X$ such that $T_\gamma^*\to S$, for some bounded operator $S$ on $X^*$, where the convergence is with respect to the dual topology by the dual pairing $(S,f):=Sf$ on $B(X^*)\times X^*$. Does $S$ belong to $\{T^*:T\in B(X^*)\}$, that is, is $S=T^*$ for some operator $T$ on $X$?

I doubt it but I have no counterexample.

Comment: you ask if $S  \in \{T^* \ \mid \  T \in B(X)\}$ ? and if $S \not \in \{T^* \ \mid \  T \in B(X)\}$ then to what set does it belong ?

Comment: Of what space would $B (X^\ast) $ be the dual space?

Comment: @PhoemueX: Better, dual pair $X'\times\mathcal{B}(X')$ with dual pairing $(x',T'):=Tx'$.

Comment: Your limit operator is bounded (weak-*-continuous) by the UBP: $\|T_n'\|<\infty\implies\|S\|<\infty$

Comment: @Freeze: But $Tx'$ is an element of $X'$, not a scalar.

Comment: @PhoemueX: Sure, but that is not a problem as one can analogously extend the notion to Banach-valued dual pairs; see the thread: [Dual Pairs](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1354365/79762)

Comment: @PhoemueX: I wrote a new thread for this: [Norm](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1746666/79762)