# Topology: Norm vs. Initial

Tags: functional-analysis

*This thread is for future - not for generating credits.*
*(I provided an answer as [Q&A](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/); see also [MSE-Meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/21733/79762).)*

**Topology**

Initial Topology:
$$\varphi:X\to Y:\quad\mathcal{T}X:=\varphi^{-1}[\mathcal{T}Y]$$

Norm(al) Topology:
$$\|\cdot\|:Z\to\mathbb{R}_+:\quad\mathcal{N}Z(0):=\|\mathcal{N}\mathbb{R}_+(0)\|^{-1}$$
*(Origin-System!)*

**Transform**

Transform & Norm:*
$$L:X\to Y\qquad\nu:Y\to\mathbb{R}_+$$

Initial vs. Normal:
$$\mathcal{T}X=L^{-1}[\mathcal{T}Y]\quad\mathcal{N}Y(0)=\nu^{-1}[\mathcal{N}\mathbb{R}_+(0)]$$
$$\mathcal{N}X(0)=(\nu\circ L)^{-1}[\mathcal{N}\mathbb{R}_+(0)]\\$$

Do they *reeally* agree?

**Transform: Linearity!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This answer is community wiki!*

Initial Topology:
$$\mathcal{T}X=\varphi^{-1}[\mathcal{T}Y]\iff\mathcal{N}X(x)=\varphi^{-1}[\mathcal{N}Y(\varphi x)]$$

Norm Topology:
$$\mathcal{N}Z(z)=\mathcal{N}Z(0)+z\quad\mathcal{N}Z(0)=\|\mathcal{N}\mathbb{R}_+(0)\|^{-1}$$

Linear Transform:
$$L\in\mathcal{L}:\quad L^{-1}(A+La)=L^{-1}(A)+a$$

Initial vs. Normal:

$$\mathcal{N}X(x)=L^{-1}[\mathcal{N}Y(Lx)]=L^{-1}[\mathcal{N}Y(0)+Lx]\\
=L^{-1}[\mathcal{N}Y(0)]+x=L^{-1}[\nu^{-1}[\mathcal{N}\mathbb{R}_+(0)]]+x\\
=(\nu\circ L)^{-1}[\mathcal{N}\mathbb{R}_+(0)]+x=\mathcal{N}X(0)+x=\mathcal{N}X(x)$$
Completing check!